# n-gram fuzzy matching from Dictionary

Tags: python, regex, fuzzy-search, n-gram, fuzzywuzzy

Given a string S of variable length and a dictionary D of n-grams N, I want to:

- extract all N in S that match with a fuzzy matching logic (to catch spelling errors)
- extract all Numbers in S
- show the results in the same order as they are in S

I accomplished points 1 and 2, but my approach, based on the creation of n-grams from S and fuzzy matching against the dictionary (plus matching of numbers) does not maintain the order in which the items are in S

```
from nltk import everygrams
from flask_caching import Cache
import re

string = "Hello everybody, today we have 2.000 cell phones here"
ngrams = (list(everygrams(string.split(), 1, 4)))

my_dict = {
    "brand": "ITEM_01",
    "model": "ITEM_02",
    "cell phone": "ITEM_04",
    "today" : "ITEM_05"
}

result=""
results=[] # list with final results
d = FuzzyDict(my_dict) # create the dictionary for fuzzy matching

for k in ngrams:
    candidate = ' '.join(k)
    print (f"Searching for {candidate}")
    
    try:
        #matching n-gram in Dictionary using fuzzy match
        result = d[candidate]
        print (f"Found {result}")
        results.append(result)

    except:
        print("An exception occurred") 
    
    #matching complex numbers
    numbers = re.findall(r'(?:[+-]|\()?\$?\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?\)?', candidate)
    
    #appending numbers to list
    results.extend(numbers)
        
#NOTE chronological order is not kept!

#keeping unque values since my approach will extract several instances of the same item
myset = set(results)
results_unique = list(myset)
```

This should give me "ITEM_5 2.000 ITEM_4" (now the order is casual)

Comment: Some parts of your code seem to be missing. eg. what exactly is in your "ngrams" variable? How did you create it? Because usually I would generate the ngrams in the loop to save memory. I would assume there is some problem there.

Comment: Indeed, I missed a line of code for the generation of n-grams:    
    ngrams = (list(everygrams(string.split(), 1, 4)))